# How does a flow of architecture of a digital banking system looks like?

Tags: design, distributed-system

I am working at a digital banking company i.e company that provides software for banks so that the customers of that bank can use banking services via smartphone.

But the documentation there is non-existent. I am always confused about the working of the various types of payments like:

- How does transfer of fund between same banks occur?
- How does transfer of fund between different banks occur?
- How does transfer of fund via QR transfer occur?
- How does money gets topped up in smartphone?

And so many. I've a gist about this but no matter how much I look at logs, I can't exactly trace out the flow. I've asked with senior colleagues and they too just know what I know i.e abstract view. I don't have access to the codebase as I'm a sysadmin(I think it'd help me). It's been a long time(5 months) since I joined this job and now I'm too afraid to ask about it to developers!

Is there something that I can ready like a textbook or something? I'm a cs grad so I've decent idea about subjects like "software architecture and engineering". Are system design books helpful in my case? I don't think these systems are anything out of the ordinary, but I need to understand the flow of architecture of these apps properly on minute basis. From hitting a reverse proxy to connecting with core banking system.

Comment: Can you explain why you, as sysadmin, needs this kind of information? How relevant it would be to make your work easier or more efficient? One thing IMO to understand is that of encapsulation: that you shouldn't need to understand inner workings of a system to be able to efficiently use it. Just understanding it's API should be sufficient.

Comment: You are not helping us with that attitude. I'm tempted to close your question as too broad, as I can't imagine there exists a comprehensive answer.

Comment: Mom thought I was funny :) Deleted it.

Answer (score 2):

The internal operations of banks first started to be computerised in the 1960s, and proceeded aggressively in the 1970s. Keeping the books hasn't been done on paper for decades.

So I'm not exactly sure what a "digital banking system" is, as distinct from any ordinary banking system as we know it.

> How does transfer of fund between same banks occur?

When transferring money within the same bank, the bank simply makes entries into its own books (or "ledger"), debiting one account and crediting the other.

> How does transfer of fund between different banks occur?

There are a large number of schemes, but most commonly each bank maintains an account with the other - called a correspondent account - and they synchronise entries not only into their respective customer accounts but also into their own correspondent accounts.

The effect is that the transfer is not direct, as it is for a same-bank transfer.

Periodically (possibly several times a day nowadays, but the frequency needn't be daily, or regular in time), the banks "settle" the net difference of their correspondent accounts which may have accumulated.

They needn't necessarily do this settlement directly - they can also settle via a third correspondent that is common between them, such as the central bank of the state.

> How does transfer of fund via QR transfer occur?

It would depend on the scheme, but if it involves a bank to bank transfer, then it presumably triggers a transfer in the ordinary way.

Alternatively, it may be achieved via electronic payment infrastructure (like Visa or MasterCard), the details of which are more complicated again, but involve the same essential relationships of banks (or financial institutions more broadly) and correspondent accounts to bridge any gap between banks.

> How does money gets topped up in smartphone?

Companies maintain a system of "client accounts" or "customer accounts", very similar essentially to what banks do.

When "topping up", the company takes your cash or receives a transfer (or accepts a promise from a financial institution), and records that receipt (or "receivable") in their ledger, and also credits your customer account in their ledger.

> Is there something that I can ready like a textbook or something?

Yes, the basics would be covered in an accountancy textbook.

Every ordinary business is essentially involved in transferring money to other businesses, often via the accounts each holds with a bank.

The bank account that an ordinary business holds with its own bank, is basically the analogy of the "correspondent account" that banks hold with each other, and the interactions (like settlement, reconciliation, and so on) are similar in principle.

Comment: I'm from Asian country and digital banking started just few years ago here.

Comment: @achhainsan, you mean they were still using tabulating machines and paper books in each branch? No computers?

Comment: This answer (while impressive) would benefit if an explanation of how transactions work in code and the importance of being able to roll them back.

Comment: @candied_orange, the OP's questions danced across the entire financial architecture of our society. I think you may be asking a more specific question about database technologies. Certainly, a "transaction" in accountancy is not necessarily the same thing as a database transaction, and a "roll back" is not necessarily a term an accountant would understand (and certainly not in the way a database developer would).

Comment: @Steve which is exactly why a programmer tackling automating this for the first time needs a heads up. Computers don’t always do things atomically. But is up to you if the upvote is worth the edit.

Comment: @candied_orange, I'm not clear how to integrate a point about database transactions, with the existing content of my answer. I mean, you can't seriously be suggesting he's going to "tackle automating" the country's banking system? Actual computer systems which run banking are multi-billion pound developments. Also, an interbank transaction isn't "atomic" in the way a database developer understands the term - it involves a complicated back-and-forth, which is why until relatively recently most such transactions took days to execute. (1/2)

Comment: Obviously, transfers are designed ultimately to achieve system-wide consistency, but it's a transaction guaranteed by the human organisation and the design of the processes of the institutions involved. It's not like some coder just types "begin tran ... commit tran", and everything everywhere is then done. A lot of bank computer systems still date from the era when guys would be scurrying between computer centres with tape spools - in other words, they are designed to work with air gaps, and the computers only guarantee database "transactional consistency" locally, not systemically. (2/2)

Comment: @Steve ya know, if you had mentioned that in your answer instead of spending your energy arguing with me you'd have earned an upvote.

Comment: @candied_orange, the only reason I'm saying any of it is because you've teased it out of me! Feel free to upvote the comments, if not the answer!

Comment: @Steve NO.Everything was already computerized but there were no apps to do the payment. That's all. I work in a company that allows apps to make payment. That's it.

Comment: PS can you recommend me 5 such books on accountancy which would make me understand everything that happens in digital payment in banks?

Comment: @achhainsan, I'm not quite sure what to recommend. Accountancy tenets can be sought from any educational textbook relevant to your jurisdiction. I'm not sure though whether books exist that concisely describe - in a way useful to a software developer - how payments are executed end-to-end through the banking system though. That too is country-specific and the finest details are probably bank-specific. What I know myself, I've acquired from anecdote, ad-hoc research, and osmosis.

Comment: @achhainsan recommendations are off topic here.